# Initialization Errors with React Native Tutorials

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8, xcode8-beta3

I just installed React Native, and am attempting to follow tutorials on the React Native website to get accustomed to it. However every tutorial I end up doing just gives me a big red error screen in the iOS Simulator.

As an example, I followed the "Hello World" tutorial on the React Native website

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { AppRegistry, Text } from 'react-native';

class HelloWorldApp extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Text>Hello world!</Text>
    );
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

but am met with this error after compiling and running in the simulator"

"Application TestProject has not been registered. This is either due to a require() error during initialization or failure to call AppRegistry.registerComponent"

I'm confused because I know nothing yet about RN, am following their tutorials to the letter, and am getting errors.

Please advise?

Comment: Which version of `React Native` are you using ?

Comment: The very latest they have on their site. I performed the install instructions as they had them on their site 2 days ago. So...version 0.30?

Comment: Which OS are you using? `Linux`, `Windows` or `Mac` ? Are you sure `packager` is running when you did `react-native run-ios` ?

Comment: OS X. I'm following the tutorials to the letter from installation, all the way to the Hello World tutorial. Everything current on their website. I'm typing in exactly as they show. Nothing deviated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There might be two possibilities as I know of:

1. When you run `react-native run-ios` the `packager` didn't start automatically. If that's the case, **Run the Packager Manually**. To do so:

In one Tab of your terminal run `react-native start` and in another run `react-native run-ios`.

2. Or while following the document from react native's site, you might have changed the app's name. Like:

You created a project using `react-native init AwesomeProject`. The Project's name here is `AwesomeProject`.

And then changed your default `index.ios.js` and replaced the Component's name with `HelloWorldApp`.

```
class HelloWorldApp extends Component

AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);
```

Comment: Ok Packager IS running, so it has to be the second issue, which I was completely unaware of.

I wasn't aware the project name signified the component. Thank you for this. I'll try to correct and report back.

Comment: Yes, this was it. So the project name 100% always has to be the registered components name?

Comment: When you create a new react-native project with a name (`AwesomeProject`), it creates some files like `AppDelegate.m` and others which uses the same project name in their code. While you changed the Component's name only on `index` file and the code `AppRegistry.registerComponent('HelloWorldApp', () => HelloWorldApp);` searches for the `HelloWorldApp` as a registered module on those files which obviously has `AwesomeProject` as registered.

Comment: Thank you for your help. This almost deterred me from learning.